# How Can I Fix an Array Index is Out of Range Error in Unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am making a slide show in Unity. I have 2 scenes set up each with an array full of images. As I press the right arrow key I am able to iterate through the array, displaying each image in that index along the way. I'm also able to move to the next scene in my project with a tap of the right arrow key once I reach the end of the array in the current scene. So far, so good.

The issues arise the moment I try to move backwards through the slideshow. I can jump backwards through the images in the array in the current scene with ease by pressing the left arrow key, but the moment I try to move back to the previous scene, or I'm at the beginning of my array and I press the left arrow key, I'm hit with an error:

> Array index is out of range

I sort of understand what the computer's saying - that I'm trying to access an index of the array that doesn't exist, but I'm drawing a blank on how to solve the issue.

#### Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadImage : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Image newImage;
[SerializeField] Image[] nextImage;
int currentImageIndex = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    GetNextImage();
} 

private Image GetNextImage()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && currentImageIndex < nextImage.Length)
    {
        newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex];
        newImage.enabled = true;
        currentImageIndex++;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && currentImageIndex == nextImage.Length)
    {
        LoadNextScene();
    }

    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && currentImageIndex <= nextImage.Length)
    {
        Debug.Log("poop.");
        newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex - 1];  //<--- I think this is 
        newImage.enabled = false;                     //     the problem 
                                                      //     child.
        currentImageIndex--;                          
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && currentImageIndex == nextImage.Length - nextImage.Length)
    {
        LoadPreviousScene();
    }
        return newImage;
}


private void LoadNextScene()
{
    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);
}

private void LoadPreviousScene()
{
    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex - 1);
}
```

}

So to reiterate: I move through the array of images one at a time pressing the right arrow key. Once I reach the end of the array I press the right arrow key once more and I'm taken to the next scene in my project. However once I'm in the next scene I can't go back to the previous scene because of the "Array index is out of range" error - my LoadPreviousScene() method doesn't get called.

When I'm on the first Index of the array I want to be able to mash that left arrow key and be thrown back into the previous scene.

Comment: You need to make sure that `currentImageIndex - 1` is not out of range, using `if` statements.

Comment: if `currentImageIndex == 0` then `newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex - 1];` will be out of range: `nextImage[-1]`

Comment: `nextImage` has a `.Length` property.  This will tell you exactly how many elements are in the array.  If, for example, your array has 10 elements, and you access the `10` index, it will be out of range.  In C# indexes are 0 based, so a 10 element array has an index range from 0-9.  As @DmitryBychenko has pointed out, you are trying to access the `-1` index which would never be valid.  Its not clear what you want your code to do ultimately but the one thing you should _for sure do_ is check the length before accessing an index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of this condition:

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && currentImageIndex <= nextImage.Length)
```

When you do `newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex - 1];` you need to make sure that `currentImageIndex` is bigger than 0.

Here's how I would write your method:

```
private Image GetNextImage()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        if(currentImageIndex < nextImage.Length)
        {
            newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex++];
            newImage.enabled = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            LoadNextScene();
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        if(currentImageIndex > 0)
        {
            newImage = nextImage[currentImageIndex--];  
            newImage.enabled = false;                     
        }
        else
        {
            LoadPreviousScene();
        }
    } 
    return newImage;
}
```

Note I've separated the conditions between keys and indexes, since there is not much sense in testing the same condition twice.

Comment: But with currentImageIndex++ and currentImageIndex-- the currentImageIndex will be updated in the next iteration. It should be ++currentImageIndex and --currentImageIndex .

Comment: @GhAyoub That might be correct, but if you look at the code in the question, the adding/subtracting value of `currentImageIndex` is done *after* setting `newImage` - I simply followed that.

Comment: Yes I can understand ^^ Good job though.